# After import csv file to datagrid i need to add or insert new records to datagridview then export lastest data to csv file

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJLZr.png) **After import csv file to datagrid i need to add or  insert new records to datagridview then export lastest data to csv file
after adding new data to datagrid imported data is not showing in datagrid only new data is showing**

- this is my code: I don't where I am going wrong.
- -- here I need to add new data; and click on add; with new row.

  ```
   namespace Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable
   {
     public partial class Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable : Form
     {
      public Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable()
      {
       InitializeComponent();
      }
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     int selectedRow;
     private void Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       //Create Headers for the dataTable
       table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
       table.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
       table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
       table.Columns.Add("Profession", typeof(string));
       dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
   //Add to DataGridView
   bool found = false;
   private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {           
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDTxt.Text))
       {                
           if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
               {
                   if(Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == IDTxt.Text)
                   {
                       found = true;                          
                       MessageBox.Show("Person Id already Exist");                           
                   }                        
               }
               if(!found)
               {
                   table.Rows.Add(IDTxt.Text, fisrtTxt.Text, SurNameTxt.Text, ProfesTxt.Text);
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                   cleatTxts();

               }
           }                
       }
       else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDTxt.Text))
       {               
           label1.Text = "Person Id should not be empty";
       }
   }
   private void ImportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {           
       try
       {
           OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

           if (DialogResult.OK == dlg.ShowDialog())
           {
               string path = dlg.FileName;
               BindData(path);
               MessageBox.Show("Import Action Compelted");
           }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("The path does not exist", ex);
       }
   }
   private void BindData(string filePath)
   {
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
       if (lines.Length > 0)
       {
           //first line to create header
           string firstLine = lines[0];
           string[] headerLabels = firstLine.Split(',');
           foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
           {
               table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerWord));
           }
           //For Data 
           for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
           {
               string[] dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
               DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
               int columnIndex = 0;
               foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
               {
                   dr[headerWord] = dataWords[columnIndex++];
               }
               table.Rows.Add(dr);
           }
           dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
       }

    }
  ```

[Atfter add new data imported data went i need want old and new data in datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wSvE.png)

[This i need to do but after adding only new data is coming output attcahed in other picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VXer.png)

Comment: You are aware that the code is “creating’ a “new” `DataTable` in the `BindData` method? When you add the row in the `BtnAdd_Click` event, it is using the “global” `DataTable` `table`, that is no longer used as a `DataSource` to the grid. So when you add the data source to the grid in the add button click event. It is using the global variable `table.` I assume you DO NOT want to create a new table in the `BindData` method.

Comment: Thank you its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, when the form loads, the code creates the “global” `DataTable` variable `table.` Inside the load event, the code creates the four columns and then sets the grids `DataSource` to this table. The form is displayed and we can see a grid with one “empty” new row displayed.

Then you click the `ImportBtn` button, it fires it click event, where the user picks a file, then this file path is passed to the method, `BindData.` Inside `BindData` …

The code “creates” a new LOCAL `DataTable` variable named `table.` Note, this is a different local table and NOT the `table` defined globally in the load event. The code creates the columns, add the rows, then sets this local `table` as a `DataSource` to the grid. When execution leaves the `BindData` method, the local variable `table` will go out of scope.

Therefore, after the imported data is displayed, we add some legal values to the text boxes and click the ADD button. In the `BtnAdd_Click` event, it uses the “global” variable `table` to add the row to. However, this `table` is empty because in the import code, it used a different local `table.` So when you add the row and set the grids `DataSource`  to `table`… it will only have the one newly added row.

I will assume you do NOT want to create a new `table` variable in the `BindData` method. Instead we want to use the “global” `DataTable` variable `table` to add the imported rows to. This change is seen below. Here the changes are that instead of referencing the new row cells using the name, I used indexes. Also, a check is made to catch if the read row read from the csv file has fewer values than the data row has columns and vice versa. The code simply used the smaller of the two lengths to stay inbounds. `totCols = Math.Min(dataRowCount, dataWords.Length);`

```
private void BindData(string filePath) {
  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
  if (lines.Length > 0) {
    int totCols;
    int dataRowCount = table.Columns.Count;
    string[] dataWords;
    DataRow dr;
    for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++) {
      dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
      dr = table.NewRow();
      totCols = Math.Min(dataRowCount, dataWords.Length);
      for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < totCols; colIndex++) {
        dr[colIndex] = dataWords[colIndex];
      }
      table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
  }
}
```

Next in the ADD button click event, since the grid is already bound to the variable `table,` after we add the row, we simply call the tables `AcceptChanges` method and this should update the grid.

```
if (!found) {
  table.Rows.Add(IDTxt.Text, fisrtTxt.Text, SurNameTxt.Text, ProfesTxt.Text);
  table.AcceptChanges();
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

***Edit update as per comment…***

@Caius Jard … Thanks for the info. I switched the `ReadAllLines` to `ReadLines` and switched the type of `lines` to `IEnumerable<string>.` …

Before this change, I changed the code as you suggested with `row.ItemArray = line.Split(',');` and this failed. The error was that it did not like the `string` number when adding this to the first column `Id` which is an `int` column.

I copied the same code the OP used so the `Id` column in the table is an `int` type. Initially I though I must be using a `string` instead of an `int`, however this is not the case… So, this seems odd to me since the first code I posted in my answer assigns the value in column zero (0) as…

```
dr[colIndex] = dataWords[colIndex];
```

Since `dataWords` is a `string[]` array, I was wondering why I did not get the same error. From a couple of tests, it appears there is a conversion going on behind the scenes when the data is loaded from the CSV file and also when the row is added to the table in the `ADD` event. In the add event, the code is simply adding the row from the text boxes…

```
table.Rows.Add(IDTxt.Text, fisrtTxt.Text, SurNameTxt.Text, ProfesTxt.Text);
```

Here `IDTxt.Text` is obviously a `string`, however, if the `string` is a valid `int`, then this will get converted to an `int` when added. I would think this would throw the same error even if the text was a valid `int.`

This had me scratching my head as in my past experience, this would throw the grids `DataError.` At least I though it would. It appears it is ok and will do the behind-the-scenes conversion as long as the `string` is a valid `int.` I tested this in the `BindData` method, such that the `Id` was something like “a5.” When the table was filled, I got the format exception complaining about the bad `int` value.

So, in either case, checking for a valid `int` value would appear necessary to avoid getting these exceptions. In this case, when reading the file, the code below simply ignores rows with invalid `Id` values.

Also, if a line in the CSV has fewer values than the data row has columns, then that CSV row is ignored. If the line in the CSV has more values than the number of columns in the data row, then only the first n values are used. Where n is the number of columns in the data row.

In addition, when reading the CSV file, a check is made to see if there are “duplicate” `Id`s in the CSV file. If a duplicate `Id` is found in the CSV then, that row is ignored.

The `int.TryParse` method is used when reading the CSV file for converting the `Id` number from a `string` to an `int.` It is also used when adding a new row from the text boxes. If the `Id` text is not a valid `int` number, the row is not added.

The updated `BindData` method is below and renamed to `AddCSVDataToGrid.`

```
private void AddCSVDataToGrid(string filePath) {
  IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
  int tableColumnCount = table.Columns.Count;
  string[] dataValues;
  DataRow dr;
  foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1)) { // <- Skip the header row
    dataValues = line.Split(',');
    if (dataValues.Length >= tableColumnCount) { 
      if (int.TryParse(dataValues[0], out int idValue)) { // <- check if Id is a valid int
        if ((table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0) {  // <- check if Id is duplicate
          dr = table.NewRow();
          dr[0] = idValue;
          for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < tableColumnCount; colIndex++) {
            dr[colIndex] = dataValues[colIndex];
          }
          table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        else {
          // MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Id value in CSV file ..." + dataValues[0] + " - Skipping duplicate Id row");
        }
      }
      else {
        // MessageBox.Show("Person Id in CSV is not an integer..." + dataValues[0] + " Skiping invalid Id row");
      }
    }
    else {
      // MessageBox.Show("Missing data in CSV ..." + dataValues[0] + " - Skipping CSV row");
    }
  }
}
```

Next is the updated ADD button click event.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string idText = IDTxt.Text.Trim();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idText) && int.TryParse(idText, out int idValue)) {
    if ((table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0) {
      table.Rows.Add(idValue, fisrtTxt.Text.Trim(), SurNameTxt.Text.Trim(), ProfesTxt.Text.Trim());
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("Person Id already Exist");
    }
  }
  else {
    label1.Text = "Person Id should not be empty && must be a valid int value";
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick n easy way to set row data: `row.ItemArray = line.Split(',');` (original code takes only datatable.Columns.Length number of words; could add a .Take if you think there will be more/wasn't any indication there would be fewer?).. Also consider ReadLines instead of ReadAllLines?